# how to insert images in a php mysql blog and display them at exact position

Tags: php, mysql, image, blogs

I am creating a website where the admin needs to publish his works. I need to make a control panel for him to update the website with new content. Content will be in the form of research papers i.e kinda like blog posts. I have successfully enabled an interface where he can enter a title, body text and tags or keywords.

How do I create something with which he can upload multiple images to make his work more appealing - i.e to allow him to insert images at the exact positions where he want them to be displayed.

I've searched a lot and not been able to find a suitable answer

Answer (score 0):

Use uploadify and set its multi param to true

```
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />


        $(function() {
            $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                'multi'    : true,
                'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : '/uploadify/uploadify.php' ,
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        // Use the 'file' object to get the filename and stuff and put it somewhere on the page.
    }
            });
        });
```

Server Side:

```
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo $targetFolder . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```